# Translating "A letter for the public to read" and German infinitive verb grammar

Tags: grammar, translation, english-to-german, infinitive

I'd like to translate the English phrase `A letter for the public to read` into German. To be clear, I mean the phrase to suggest a letter that the public can read, as if addressed to the public.

Google Translate suggests `Ein Brief für die Öffentlichkeit zu lesen`.

Reverso suggests `Ein Brief für die Öffentlichkeit, um zu lesen`.

Linguatec and Systranet suggest `Ein Brief, damit die Öffentlichkeit liest`. This is correctly retranslated to English by Google Translate.

Are any of these good translations? I wonder about the grammar.

If `lesen` is translated as `to read`, I don't know why `Ein Brief für die Öffentlichkeit lesen` would be incorrect.

I suppose I'm asking about German infinitive verb grammar. For example, in English a valid phrase is `cake for everyone to eat`. Would it be correct German grammar to say `Kuchen für jeder essen`? Or `Kuchen, den jeder essen`?

Comment: In what way is that different from an [_open letter_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_letter)?

Comment: I suppose it isn't different from an open letter, but the English phrase also suggests that the public should actually read the letter, not just have access to it.

Comment: @chirlu: Open letters are not typically *addressed* at the public, as requested by the OP.

Comment: @O.R. : The original term does *not* say to whom the letter is literally addressed - It says who should read it, which is not necessarily the same person (and also a typical trait of an open letter). And jaycer: Why exactly should the writer give the public access to the letter if he doesn't want them to read it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The German standing expression would be "ein offener Brief". Although it is typically addressed *to some specific addressee*, the intention really is to be read by the *public* - for what other reason should it be "open"?.

And the Internet translates are, unfortunately, all wrong as already pointed out. If you want a literal translation, that would go like *ein Brief an die Öffentlichkeit*, or, even more literal, *ein Brief, den die Öffentlichkeit/jeder lesen sollte*. (I'd rather say "jeder" here)

Comment: I agree, the "to read"-bit is commonly not used at all in German, as it is redundant. What else would one do with a letter? I would say it is redundant in the English example as well, but of course could still be what is typically used.

Answer (score 2):

unfortunately the google translation is wrong. you could say "Ein an die Öffentlichkeit gerichteter Brief" for example.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using it as a title, I would even suggest "(Ein) Brief an die Öffentlichkeit"